# "COUNT field incorrect" error when column name contains a question mark

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-access

This error seem to point to date columns in my dataframe. I know that this error appears when I try to do `df_tosql` in MS Access with unconverted date columns.
Im trying to fix this error by checking other date columns that I didnt include in converting to datetime data type but I think I've included all of it but I still encounter this error.

I want to know what COUNT field incorrect (17) means and how to know which 17 columns is this error pertaining to. Initially I have 17 datetime columns so I know this error pertains to datecolumns but I missed one and added it but it still shows (17) in the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually from one column name that has '?'. MS Access apparently doesn't allow some special characters in column names.

Comment: I have added a workaround in the sqlalchemy-access wiki page [here](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access/wiki/%5Bknown-issue%5D-column-names-that-contain-question-marks).